# Complex Summing Values in a Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I have formula result that returns this `+10+5+1+40`, as text. I want to then sum the those numbers to get the total.

The result could be any number of values, so like `+2+5` or `+10+5+7+1+8`.

In case it is helpful, the original data set is something like this `S10_S5_S1_S40` or this `E_E_S2_S5`. I have stripped out everything except the numbers next to S, which is what I want to add.

Lastly, I am posting on superuser as I want to avoid VBA if I can.

**Update**

Through this formula:
 `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D25,"E",""),"_",""),"S","=",1),"S","+")`

I've gotten it down to this `=10+5+1+40`, where D25 = `S10_S5_S1_S40` ...  but that is really the same as having a `+` in front, I guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only have 1 or 2 digit numbers as per your examples then this "array formula" will sum all the "S" numbers from D25

`=SUM(IF(MID(D25,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25))),1)="S",(0&SUBSTITUTE(MID(D25,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25)))+1,2),"_",""))+0))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

so if D25 contains `S10_S5_S1_S40` that will give you the result 56

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Changing my answer because even though this is a bit of long, nasty formula, it's easier to implement than the `Evaluate` in the named range.

Answer (score 3):

There is no worksheet formula that does that. You can use the old Excel 4 macro function EVALUATE(), but it can only be used in a named range.

So, if you have data in column D, and you have the substitute formula in column E, for example, select F25 and create a new named formula with the Name Manager. Give it the name "EvaluateMe" and let it refer to

```
=EVALUATE(Sheet1!E25)
```

Then, enter

```
=EvaluateMe
```

into cell F25 and the result will display. This named range uses a relative reference, and if the active cell was in F25 when you defined it, it will always try to evaluate the cell directly to the left.

Comment: Suh-Weet! THanks for this. I was looking for the evaluate function, but didn't really now how it works. Good, good stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This derives from Barry’s “awesome” answer.  The following “array formula”

> `=SUM(IF(MID(D25,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25))),1)="S",MID(D25,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25)))+1,IFERROR(FIND("_",D25,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25)))+1),LEN(D25)+1)-(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D25)))+1))+0))`

(entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) will add all the ‘S’ numbers in cell `D25`, regardless of length; so if `D25` contains “S10_S5_S1_S240”, the above formula will give you the result 256. 
This will also handle negative numbers: “S10_S5_S–1_S240” will yield 254.

I have not tested this exhaustively. 
I’ll probably find something wrong with it Monday morning, myself.  :)